# Running Multiple Spring Projects with different Spring Versions on Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

```
Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.1. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.1 schema.
Offending resource: class path resource [authentication-context.xml]
```

In my Eclipse workspace are a set of Mavenised Spring projects on Spring verion 3.0.6..
It's a fairly large, complicated application, about a year old, with a parent pom and 6/7 sub-poms for different components. I'll title it Project A for now.
Project A has two webapps within it, a public based website and a backoffice administration area.

Recently a seperate application was built for Project A to interact with via REST calls.
However this new application, Project B runs on Spring 3.1.1. This is in the same Eclipse workspace.

Project A's customer website and Project B ran fine on the same tomcat, there were no confused dependencies.

But now that development has started on Project A's backoffice interacting with Project B, there is a conflict, in the Spring security versions when Tomcat is launched.

Current solutions we've attempted have failed, but we haven't tried updating the

- Spring version in Project A (fairly sure things will break and not sure it's worth the time retesting) and
- downgrading Spring in Project B seems like a horrible precedent to set.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Are they compiled together or run inside the same application context? There shouldn't be an issue if they're just interacting via web service calls.  If they're attempting to use the same or overlapping contexts, that will create a problem

Comment: Go through the changelogs between Spring 3.0.6 and 3.1.1. Things may not be so bad and you may be able to upgrade without any glitches.

Comment: @ChrisThompon - They're run locally for dev within the same context, but not when deployed beyond that.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar - Thanks, that seemed like the smarter choice.

What we've decided to do right now, is to edit the project types in Eclipse and see if we can run them as D.Web Projects in case we run into a similar situation in the future. Will report back on how it goes. Thanks guys.